# Как убрать ограничения на время жизни javascript-скрипта

Tags: javascript

По мере усложнения моего проекта, скрипты стали требовать все больше и больше времени для выполнения (обработка ЖПС данных, там большие массивы координат). Наступил момент, когда браузер ругается на скрипт - предполагает, что скрипт завис и предлагает его прервать, однако скрипт выполняется, просто ему не хватает стандартного временного интервала.
Как и где изменить стандартные настройки времени жизни скрипта, если такое предусмотрено?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Допустим Вам нужно выполнить функцию trade 10 миллионов раз, конечно же браузер будет ругаться, но можно убрать ругань потеряв немного производительности. Единственное что для этого нужно: вызывать trade в цикле в течении n секунд, а каждые n+1 секунд через window.setInterval возобновлять выполнение цикла. С подборкой времени поэкспериментируйте сами.

```
 <body>
<div id="gh"></div>
<script>
var t=1;
function trade() {
    t++;
    time2=new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime()-time2<50) {};
};
function runtrade() {
    gh.innerHTML=t;
    time1=new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime()-time1<2000) trade();
};
runtrade();
window.setInterval("runtrade();", 3000);
</script></body>
```

upd: я на одном хостере круглосуточно крутил скрипт php выполняя его 25 секунд и вызывая file_get_contents(этот же скрипт) в конце.
Хостер только через месяц меня заблокировал до снятия с сайта самозацикленных скриптов. Тоже на эту же тему.
upd2: можно попробовать в конце выполнения runtrade вставить window.setTimeout("runtrade();", 50); это наверно даже эффективнее будет, чем через setInterval.
  `<body>
<div id="gh"></div>
<script>
var t=1;
function trade() {
    t++;
    time2=new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime()-time2<50) {};
};
function runtrade() {
    gh.innerHTML=t;
    time1=new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime()-time1<2000) trade();
    window.setTimeout("runtrade();", 50);
};
runtrade();
</script></body>`

Comment: интересный вариант, вполне перспективно...

Answer (score 1):

Менять надо в настройках браузера так как все зависит от движка, который последний использует. Так на вскидку, в firefox - вбиваем в адрессную строку about:config и увеличиваем javascript.options.mem.high_water_mark. В других браузерах действуем по аналогии. Но этот метод будет действовать только при отладке, не будете же вы проделывать все эти манипуляции конечным пользователям. А так только оптимизация самый верный путь.

Answer (score 1):

Может стоит часть логики перенести на сервер, а результат получать с помощью ajax. Профилировщиком пройтись по скрипту и найти узкие места. Я думаю есть что оптимизировать.
Считаю данное решение всё же лучше, чем подкручивать стандартные настройки браузера.

Comment: перенес, конечно же. проблема в том, что данные систем навигации идут массивом, в котором может быть 100 элементов, а может быть несколько тысяч, и их обработка необходима непосредственно в жаваскрипт, поскольку результат сразу уходит на гугль мапс..